# Symfony .htaccess - 500 third level domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I'm my application on subdirectory in www.example.com/aplication/v1 and I have a third level domain to this in v1.example.com. 
I'm using symfony2 and in my .htacess I have this:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

and this is my app.php

```
 <?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
include_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

All works well in www.example.com/aplication/v1, but 500 if I try v1.example.com. 
I ask to support of my hosting and They say the problem is in my .htacess. 
How fix it?

update: Maybe I must update my rewrite condition in .htaccess?

Comment: I suspect that has todo with the require and include...

Comment: I Also suspect that, but how can i set that redirect for works well with both the domain?

Comment: just use absolute paths

Comment: this not work, I presume becuase i use symfony and this file are protected (can't see with abslute path).

Comment: Do you get an error in the error log? /var/log/apache2/...

Comment: I'm waiting this, i cannot ssh the server. But maybe i must modify rewriteCond in my htaccess?

Comment: No... this does not respect the rewrite of Apache

Comment: the rewritecondition of .htacess? So I can't se solution

Comment: otherwise, i add all my htacess in the question.

Comment: Where does v1.example.com point? same as example.com or to subdirectory v1?

Comment: To www.example.com/api/web

Comment: same htaccess on v1.example.com?

Comment: wait, v1.example.com don't exist, simply point on www.example.com/api/web. In fact if I echo 'test' in app.php before that require I can see 'test' in both of path. Sure the problem is that require, but I think the solution will be in the .htacess

Comment: I would try to use absolute paths in there and see what it does

Comment: permission denied, i use symfony and block acess to certain file(configuration) with absolute path

Comment: I see that not work after tried, non presume it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this adding again the redirect to third domain level, like this:

```
 #redirect for service
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^v1\.example\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /application/v1/$1 [L]
```

I didnt think that I must the redirect all the request under my project, not only the root.